# Best way to parse this file to access the tab separated table at the end?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have about 15,000 text files with the following format (sample to download is below):

https://easyupload.io/res1so

The part I am interested is the table at the end that looks like:

```
 1     1   GLY       HA2   H      3.55        .     2
 2     1   GLY       HA3   H      3.76        .     2
 3     2   VAL       H     H      8.52        .     1
 4     2   VAL       HA    H      4.20        .     1
 5     2   VAL       HB    H      2.02        .     1
```

I don't have a lot of experience in parsing files, but figured a lot of the people here would. Can I get some advice on how to programmatically extract just this part of the file?

For example, is there a way to read the file only between the lines:

```
_Chem_shift_ambiguity_code
```

and

```
_stop
```

Would the best approach be to use regular expressions to search each line with the readline() method until I have reached the appropriate part, and then toggle 'on' something that continually appends the lines to a pandas dataframe?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you actually tried on your end? Could you provide an example of what you're currently working with? What about that example are you having problems with? It's hard to know at the moment exactly what you're asking for help on.

Comment: For example, I could read each line of the file into memory, but I don't know how I would begin searching for the appropriate line where the table begins with some logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way for this kind of parsing is to use a boolean variable to record whether we are inside the block to process or not and toggle it when we find  the keyword:

```
with open(filename) as fd:
    inblock = False
    for line in fd:
        if inblock:                        # we are inside the block here
            if len(line.strip()) == 0:
                continue                   # ignore blank lines inside block
            elif 'stop_' in line:
                inblock = False
                break                      # stop processing the file
            else:                          # ok, we can process that line
                ...
        else:                              # still waiting for the initial keyword
            if '_Chem_shift_ambiguity_code':
                inblock = True             # ok we have found the beginning of the block
```

Comment: Hi, yes, thank you -- I have constructed something similar but am getting regular expression errors when searching for the keywords

Comment: @Vranvs That is the reason why SO rules asks you to provide your code. If you had, someone could have explained the error and say how to fix...

Comment: Sorry - I wrote it after I posted this question, trying to concurrently work on it. I guess I mostly wanted affirmation that this was the right approach. Thank you very much!